# Removing unwanted header of ActionColumn

Tags: yii2, kartik-v

I'm using ActionColumn of kartik, which creates unwanted header(see my attachement)[image]

This header is nowhere coded!!
Any ideas how to remove it?
Here is code

```
[
    'class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn',
    'dropdown' => false,
    'headerOptions' => ['width' => '80'],
    'vAlign' => 'top',
    'template' => '{rename_folder}<br>{create_folder}',
    'buttons' => [
        'create_folder' => function ($model) {
            $bez = "erzeugen";
            return Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-close"></span>', ['/mail/mail-eingang/createfolder', 'bez' => $bez], ['title' => 'Ordner erzeugen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0']]);
        },
        'rename_folder' => function ($model) {
            $bez = "umbenennen";
            return Html::a('<span class="fa fa-folder-open"></span>', ['/mail/mail-eingang/renamefolder', 'bez' => $bez], ['title' => 'Ordner umbenennen', 'data' => ['pjax' => '0']]);
        },
],
```

Comment: add complete gridivew code i dont think it is coming fromthe action column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want remove header add this to your column config:

`'header' => '',`